Easier way to use ObjectID in MongoDB and pydantic
I have a custom pydantic model for MongoDb's ObjectID.

class PyObjectId(ObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(cls, _source_type: Any, _handler: Any) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        return core_schema.json_or_python_schema(
            json_schema=core_schema.str_schema(),
            python_schema=core_schema.union_schema(
                [
                    core_schema.is_instance_schema(ObjectId),
                    core_schema.chain_schema(
                        [
                            core_schema.str_schema(),
                            core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(cls.validate),
                        ]
                    ),
                ]
            ),
            serialization=core_schema.plain_serializer_function_ser_schema(str),
        )

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value):
        if not ObjectId.is_valid(value):
            raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")
        return ObjectId(value)

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(cls, _core_schema, handler):
        return handler(core_schema.str_schema())

I also have a pydantic model like this
class CommentBase(BaseModel):
    goal_id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId)
    comment_data: str
    user_id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId)
    parent_comment_id: Optional[PyObjectId] = None

    @field_serializer("goal_id")
    def serialize_object_id(self, goal_id: PyObjectId) -> ObjectId:
        return ObjectId(str(goal_id))

    @field_serializer("user_id")
    def serialize_user_id(self, user_id: PyObjectId) -> ObjectId:
        return ObjectId(str(user_id))

    @field_serializer("parent_comment_id")
    def serialize_comment_id(self, parent_comment_id: PyObjectId) -> ObjectId:
        return ObjectId(str(parent_comment_id))

I can make a object with the right attributes as shown below
goal_id=ObjectId('66865b021fabd7260195f0ff') comment_data='66865b021fabd7260195f0ff' user_id=ObjectId('66865b021fabd7260195f0ff') parent_comment_id=ObjectId('66865b021fabd7260195f0ff') created_at=datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 10, 8, 36, 24, 696544, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc) updated_at=datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 10, 8, 36, 24, 696544, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

At the moment, I have been dumping data into MongoDB with the above code, where I am serializing it every single time and then dumping the data into MongoDb.
This does not seem ideal, and I would like my class PyObjectId to handle this for me.
Please let me know how I can do it

This question is similar to: PyObjectID getting converted to string when insterted to MongoDB. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
